# Regex needed for IC number validation

Tags: regex, validation, ionic-framework, numbers

I need to validate a ***12 digit number***. In which,

1st & 2nd digits = less than 100

3rd & 4th digits = between 1 and 12

5th & 6th digits = between 1 and 31

And the remaining 6 digits can be any numbers from 0 to 9
Example **190131958103**
Can anyone give me the regular expression which satisfies the above validation?

Comment: You want to include 1 and 31 or exclude ?

Comment: I need to include 1 and 31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2-digit value is less than 100 by definition (max value is 99), so you don't need to check for that. This regex will meet your other needs:

```
^\d{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\d{6}$
```

It starts with any 2 digits; then either `01-09` or `10-12`; followed by one of `01-09`, `10-19`, `20-29` or `30-31`; followed by 6 digits.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AbtLgm/15)

**Update**

If you can't use `\d` in your pattern, replace it with `[0-9]` i.e.

```
^[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[0-9]{6}$
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I can't use '\d' and '\s' in my regex pattern. Are there any alternatives for that?

Comment: @VengatJoy see my edit, you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`

Comment: @CodeManiac since it is just for validation it doesn't really matter. Do you have a documentation link that says it's significantly slower?

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this mate**

```
^\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:[0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\d{6}$
```

In case you don't want to use `\d`

```
 ^[0-9]{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[-2])(?:[0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])[0-9]{6}$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Start of string.
- `\d{2}` - Matches any two digit number.
- `(?:0[1-9]|1[-2])` - Non capturing-group. Matches any number between 1 and 12.
- `(?:[0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])` - Non capturing-group. Matches any number between 1 and 31.
- `\d{6}` - Matches any six digit number.
- `$` - End of the string.

**P.S** - ***I suggest using non-capturing group. Because you're noting using group anywhere else again in your regex.This will improve performance.***

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dXlVx/6)

Comment: Thank you for the code with explanation. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Loose checking

You may check a Malaysian IC using this:

```
^\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\d{6}$
```

What this does is:

1. `^\d{2}` - Start of string is any 2 digits.
2. `(?:0[1-9]|1[012])` - Matches 01 to 12.
3. `(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - Matches 01 to 31.
4. `\d{6}$` - End of string is any 6 digits.

#### Strict checking

If you want to ensure that dates are valid, for example, checking which months have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days, you can use this:

```
^\d{2}(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:3[01])|(?:04|06|09|11)(?:30))\d{6}$
```

What this does is:

1. `^\d{2}` - Start of string is any 2 digits.
2. `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])` - For the months 01 to 12, match 01 to 29.
3. `(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:3[01])` - For the months 01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10 & 12, match 30 to 31.
4. `(?:04|06|09|11)(?:30)` - For the months 04, 06, 09, 11, match 30 only.
5. `\d{6}$` - End of string is any 6 digits.

[Demo](https://regexr.com/71h2u)

#### Caveats

As you can tell, this does not take into account leap years and how many days there are in February.
If you need to check for leap years, I suggest that you do not use regex for this, as it will just be too complicated.